# Meaning of "beaten to the punch"?

Tags: meaning

I just read about a guy that was beaten to the punch several times. I couldn't find a meaning of that using my dictionary or Google, so what does that mean?

Comment: @JasperLoy to be fair Google customizes searches, so maybe Roflcoptr searches for egg recipes and fruit drinks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/beat+to+the+punch) says:

> beat someone to the punch and beat someone to the draw:  to do something before someone else does it.

I'd better post before someone beats me to the punch.

Comment: Do you know if it comes from boxing? From duelling? Just curious.

Comment: Etymology online (at http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=punch) says "To beat (someone) to the punch is from 1923, a metaphor from boxing."